# Gtk Type Error thrown after cx freeze compile, (working fine in python interactive shell)

Tags: python, multithreading, gtk, cx-freeze

I'm running python 3.4 on Ubuntu 14.04. I am using gtk to code my app indicator (little icon near the clock etc). It works fine in the interactive shell. However running it after compile (with `cx-freeze`), the `gtk` app indicator is throwing an error, everything else works fine. I won't post the whole log as it's rather long. I suspected it was something with threading but even taking the code out of the thread for testing yielded the same result.

This is the line causing the error

```
(process:11923): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(process:11923): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_style_cascade_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed


(process:11923): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_style_provider_private_lookup: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

...more code omitted

ci = gtk.MenuItem('Currently Opened')
TypeError: GObject.__init__() takes exactly 0 arguments (1 given)
```

and the gtk related code:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk                    
from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as appindicator     

def mer():
            a = appindicator.Indicator.new('tim',self.imgdir+'firebird.gif', appindicator.IndicatorCategory.APPLICATION_STATUS)
            a.set_status (appindicator.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)
            m = gtk.Menu()
            oi = gtk.MenuItem( 'Open Smart Overlay' )
            ci = gtk.MenuItem('Currently Opened')
            ri = gtk.MenuItem('Recently Opened')
            qi = gtk.MenuItem( 'Quit' )
            m.append(oi)
            m.append(ci)
            m.append(ri)
            m.append(qi)
            a.set_menu(m)
            oi.show()
            ci.show()
            ri.show()
            qi.show()
            oi.connect('activate', lambda e: self.trayQueue.put(self.root.deiconify))
            ci.connect('activate', lambda: 0)
            ri.connect('activate', lambda: 0)
            def quit(item):
                gtk.main_quit()
                self.trayQueue.put(lambda :gui_base.quitter(self))
            qi.connect('activate', quit)
            while 1:
                gtk.main()  
        thread.start_new_thread(mer,())
```